# what does mean swept in lines?

Tags: geometry, circles

suppose that we have following picture
[image]

question is  which of the following  chords are parallel,suppose that  all lines are chords and we are  checking which of them is parallel

1.$a$  and $f$

2.$b$ and  $g$

3.$c$ and $h$

4.$d$ and  $i$

5.$e$ and $j$

determination of  parallel lines are described in book by this way
[image]

what does mean  angle swept between them?clearly  if two parallel angle is intersected by third one,then  sum of adjacent   angles is $180$,is this asked in this question or there is something different one?actually i mean terminology angle swept between them,thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the book is trying to be helpful by using language which suggests you can imagine rotating a chord from $a$ to $b$ to $c$ etc, and each time you add a bit to the angle so "sweeping" through the successive small angles. When you reach $180^\circ$ the chord is parallel to its original direction.

This can be shown to be consistent with any of the normal definitions of parallel in the Euclidean plane. But it suggests a way of solving this question by adding the angles which are given in the diagram.

Comment: does not seems it  a little more difficult then  usual way?

Comment: @dato Maybe it helps some people?

Comment: i am one candidate for GRE exam, is it something similar possible to come on GRE exam?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/GRE-Math-Prep-Course-Novas/dp/1889057592/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1375018142&sr=8-2&keywords=GRE+math+bible this book is

Comment: @dato If you have a way of solving it, use that. What is important is identifying the parallels, not precisely how you do it.